# How to disable number box which appear after writing number on notepad++ on file full of numbers?

Tags: notepad++

as in title ,i'm editing a files which contains much numbers and when i try to edit/write number it show a dialogue which contain the other numbers in file like when i write 0 and this numbers (056,087,089) exist in the file, dialogue appear with this numbers.
sorry i can't upload an image cause i have got only 6 reputations.

and it's lagging my notepad++ so i can't edit many numbers fast also i have to click away with mouse left-click to close it.

so i want to disable this, i hope anyone can help me

Thanks !

Comment: could it be that you have auto-complete on?

Comment: maybe ! how to disable it ?

Comment: settings -> options -> autocomplete -> uncheck "autocomplete"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to mark this question as answered:

This dialog is the autocomplete function of notepad++.
To turn it of just go to
`settings -> options -> autocomplete`  and *uncheck* autocomplete or choose *complete functions only*.

I use the german version of notepad++, so I'm not sure the names I wrote here are exactly written like in notepad++, but I'm sure one can find the right settings.